# How do you force a SharePoint hyperlink to open in different browser?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server, 2016, hyperlink, top-navigation

We use SharePoint 2016 on premise with top navigation.  Is there a way to force a hyperlink to open in Edge when clicking the link from IE 11?

I tried replacing the hyperlink URL https://site.com with microsoft-edge:https://site.com but get:

Ensure that the URL is valid and begins with either a valid character (a number sign (#) or forward slash (/)) or a valid supported protocol (for example, 'http://', 'https://', 'file://', 'ftp://', 'mailto:', 'news:').

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to do this, and if there were it would be a major security vulnerability. window.open will only open another window of whatever browser the user is in.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it is possible using SharePoint out of the box navigation functionality.